# as a directive to define a variable of the controller?

Tags: angularjs

please help solve the problem.

is a form of:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k19kcn9b/)

controller has the following variables:

```
briefApp.controller("briefController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.flagSize = true;
    $scope.flagExt = true; 
})
```

Directive change these variables:

```
briefApp.directive('attachmentValidate', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                $scope.flagSize = flagSize;              
                $scope.flagExt = flagExt;              
            });         
        }
    };
});
```

the problem is that no error messages are displayed:

```
<span class="error" ng-hide="flagSize">Размер файла превышен</span>
<span class="error" ng-hide="flagExt">Неверный формат файла</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your scope variable updation operation inside `scope.$evalAsync` because you are updating your scope from 'change' event of element. Updating scope variables from event will not run digest cycle automatically, you need to run it manually to update scope bindings by using `$scope.$evalAsync()`/ `$scope.$apply()` / `$timeout()` functions. Out of which `$scope.$evalAsync()` is more safest method, calling this method will never conflict with any currently running digest cycle.

**CODE**

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
   $scope.flagSize = flagSize;              
   scope.flagExt = flagExt;
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k19kcn9b/1/)